# how to get and set current cursor position of WPF textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to get the current cursor position from a WPF TextBox. If a `TextBox` contains text `abhishek` and cursor is blinking after `abhi` then i want that index, so that later after clearing the `TextBox` programmatically and assigning some other or same text programmatically I want to make the cursor blink just after 4 characters.

I have tried get cursor position like this,

```
_tempFuncName = txtFunctionName.Text;
_cursorPosition =  txtFunctionName.SelectionStart;
_selectionLength = txtFunctionName.SelectionLength;
```

And set back at some later stage from other event like this,

```
txtFunctionName.Text = _tempFuncName;
txtFunctionName.SelectionStart = _cursorPosition;
txtFunctionName.SelectionLength  = _selectionLength;
```

Here underscore variables are page level variables.

This code is not working. Is there some other approach?

Answer (score 17):

You can play with caretindex property of a text box

```
//You can set this property on some event
NumberOfDigits.CaretIndex = textbox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: This answer matches the answer in the OP title, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add one line to set focus on textbox otherwise everything is working fine.

```
txtFunctionName.Text = _tempFuncName; 
txtFunctionName.SelectionStart = _cursorPosition; 
txtFunctionName.SelectionLength  = _selectionLength ; 
txtFunctionName.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtFunctionName.Text = _tempFuncName; 
txtFunctionName.SelectionStart = _cursorPosition; 
txtFunctionName.SelectionLength  = _selectionLength ;
```

these statements are sufficient enough to do the req thing. i was making mistake in choosing event to write code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the focus only didn't help, but scrolling to the caret did.

```
txt_logArea.Select(txt_logArea.Text.Length, 0);
txt_logArea.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'ScrollToCaret'

Comment: Sorry! The described refers to System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.