# Setting cursor at the end of any text of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cursor-position

I have a text box with a displayed string already in it.
To bring the cursor to the textbox I am already doing

```
txtbox.Focus();
```

But how do I get the cursor at the end of the string in the textbox ?

Comment: is it WPF or winforms

Comment: May this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750505/how-to-get-and-set-current-cursor-position-of-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 170, accepted):

For Windows Forms you can control cursor position (and selection) with `txtbox.SelectionStart` and `txtbox.SelectionLength` properties. If you want to set caret to end try this:

```
txtbox.SelectionStart = txtbox.Text.Length;
txtbox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

For WPF see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888907/set-the-caret-cursor-position-to-the-end-of-the-string-value-wpf-textbox).

Comment: Which post says NOT to use SelectionStart.

Comment: I don't think we need -1, if we won't to put the input cursor at the end of textbox.

Comment: `Math.max(0, txtbox.Text.Length -1); // Math.max is the logic if length is 0`

Comment: @YuchenZhong is right, `-1` puts the insertion point *before* the last character (`her|e`) instead of *after* it (`here|`). Also, text boxes have a `.TextLength` property so all you need is `txtBox.SelectionStart = txtbox.TextLength`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the post he links is for WPF, whereas the answer given is for Windows Forms.

Comment: @Wolfgang exactly. The question is tagged WPF but the answer is about Windows Forms. WPF allows caret positioning directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oops, I missed that the question was WPF...

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Worked for me. Good for if contents of the TextBox (e.g. path to a file) is too long for the displayed box and you actually need to see the filename

Answer (score 80):

There are multiple options:

```
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
```

OR

```
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;
```

OR

```
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.Select(txtBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

Comment: That sets the selection, not the cursor position

Answer (score 12):

You can set the caret position using [TextBox.CaretIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the only thing you need is to set the cursor at the end, you can simply pass the string's length, eg:

```
txtBox.CaretIndex=txtBox.Text.Length;
```

You need to set the caret index at the length, not length-1, because this would put the caret before the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will help you...

Some time in Window Form `Focus()` doesn't work correctly. So better you can use `Select()` to focus the textbox.

```
txtbox.Select(); // to Set Focus
txtbox.Select(txtbox.Text.Length, 0); //to set cursor at the end of textbox
```

Comment: The OP asks about the cursor position, not the selection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Can you read my post correctly before comment...

Comment: From the docs [TextBox.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select(v=vs.110).aspx): **Selects a range of text in the text box.** While you can emulate positioning by manipulating the selection, it's better to just place the cursor where you want it