# ThreadSafe CaretIndex- WinForm

Tags: c#

I have a multiline Textbox that uses `threadsafe` method to call it.
After every new text, the caret ( cursor ) goes to first line position and for multiline texts. I can't read the lasts lines.

I try to use:

```
 textBox.CaretIndex = _textBox.Text.Length;
```

but it is not for `threadsafe`.

This is my code:

```
void test()
{
Thread demoThread =
               new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));
            demoThread.Start();
}
private void ThreadProcSafe()
{
    ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, textBox2, "text: ");
}
public static class ThreadHelperClass{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(Form f, Control ctrl, string text);
    /// <summary>
    /// Set text property of various controls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="form">The calling form</param>
    /// <param name="ctrl"></param>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    public static void SetText(Form form, Control ctrl, string text){
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
        // If these threads are different, it returns true. 
        if (ctrl.InvokeRequired){
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            form.Invoke(d, new object[] { form, ctrl, text });
        } else {
            ctrl.Text += text;
            ctrl.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

`ThreadHelperClass.SetText(this, richTextBox1, "output>>" + e.Data);`

I want to go at end of the Textbox ( for see the last lines text ) without clicking or moving the mouse. After a new text, caret go to end of the line.

i want to use [Setting cursor at the end of any text of a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423211/setting-cursor-at-the-end-of-any-text-of-a-textbox) at ThreadHelperClass but it gives me error

want to use

```
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.SelectionStart = txtBox.Text.Length;
OR
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;
OR
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.Select(txtBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

this is the error that I get when i using above codes in ThreadHelperClass
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.textBox2'  Download    C:\Users\work\source\repos\Download\Download\Form1.cs   108 Active

and when I use it outside of this function my application get crashed for multi thread

Comment: What is "`threadsafe` method"? Do you just mean `.Invoke(...)`?

Comment: I want to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423211/setting-cursor-at-the-end-of-any-text-of-a-textbox   inside ThreadHelperClass

Comment: when using outside of ThreadHelperClass it gives this crash :                        Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rtxtConsole' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Is this winforms or WPF? You need to provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved By using 
[Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775367/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-textbox1-accessed-from-a-thread-othe)

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

private void SetText(string text)
{
  // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
  // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
  // If these threads are different, it returns true.
  if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
  { 
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
  }
  else
  {
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
  }
}
```

in this way I can use textbox and all sub commands like Focus, Select in Cross-thread operation without crash.

```
txtBox.Focus();
txtBox.Select(txtBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

but in my Question Code there was a

```
Control ctrl
```

that didn't have Select, Focus
like to know the answer for old way too

Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling  `textBox.CaretIndex = _textBox.Text.Length;` from the GUI thread like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    () =>
    {
         textBox.CaretIndex = _textBox.Text.Length;
    });
```