# How to make caret stay at end of file path?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBox I use to display a file path and I'd like the caret and focus to always be at the end of path rather than the front. I've accomplished this with the help of this question: [Setting cursor at end of textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423211/setting-cursor-at-the-end-of-any-text-of-a-textbox). It works!

```
InitializeComponent();

FilePathTextBox.Focus();
FilePathTextBox.Select(FilePathTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
```

However, I added a browse button to the user could select their own save location, and when the folder select dialog closes, the caret returns to the front of the file path again. I tried using the click event on the browse button to call the above code but it does not work.

```
private void BrowseBtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   BackupFileLocationTextBox.Focus();
   BackupFileLocationTextBox.Select(BackupFileLocationTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
   BackupFileLocationTextBox.CaretIndex = BackupFileLocationTextBox.Text.Length;
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the selected text when the window opens, set it whenever the `TextBox` receives focus:

```
<TextBox Name="BackupFileLocationTextBox" GotKeyboardFocus="BackupFileLocationTextBox_GotKeyboardFocus"/>
```

```
private void BackupFileLocationTextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BackupFileLocationTextBox.CaretIndex = BackupFileLocationTextBox.Text.Length;
}
```

You should keep the line `FilePathTextBox.Focus();` where it is.

Note that if the user sets focus by clicking somewhere in the `TextBox`, the caret will move to the position they've clicked.

Comment: At first glance, I thought for sure this wasn't going to work, but it does exactly what I wanted. Thank you! For learning purposes, how/why does this work? Like, why does the textbox get "KeyboardFocus" when the folder select dialog close?

Comment: @liquidair You're welcome, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then :)

Comment: @liquidair To answer your question, though, the `TextBox` loses keyboard focus when the `Button` is clicked. I believe it only gets it back after being manually re-focused, at which point the code provided sets the caret position.

Comment: Interesting stuff. WPF is just insane in it's vastness. Thank you again!