# Can't visit the website through webview2 on another PC

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webview2

I'm learning C#(WPF) recently and want to open a website through webview2, my code works fine
on my PC, but after I publish my project and run it on another PC, it didn't work,the webview2 control is totally blank!I have installed .Net framework required to the second PC.
Why so? What have I done wrong?
here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView" Source="http://coinlist.co/login"></wv2:WebView2>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click">naviagte</Button>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Name="cl_url">ss</TextBox>
       
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: You need the `WebView2 Runtime` installed on the other computer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section

Comment: The first part of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625883/webview2-vb-net-cant-get-webpage-to-load/70645764#70645764) may be helpful.

Comment: @PoulBak got it,thanks