# credentials webview2 in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, webview2

I try to insert a authentification in webview2, but I have a error in my code.

The error is at the AddHandler `WebAccount.CoreWebView2.BasicAuthenticationRequested` :

> *`System.NullReferenceException` : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*

Here my code:

```
Class MainWindow
Private Site As String = "https://test.fr"
Private HTTPS_LoginOne As String = "admin"
Private HTTPS_PwdOne As String = "1234567"
Public Event BasicAuthenticationRequested As EventHandler(Of CoreWebView2BasicAuthenticationRequestedEventArgs)

Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    InitWeb()

    AddHandler WebAccount.CoreWebView2.BasicAuthenticationRequested, AddressOf Authentweb

End Sub

Private Sub Authentweb(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2BasicAuthenticationRequestedEventArgs)
    e.Response.UserName = HTTPS_LoginOne
    e.Response.Password = HTTPS_PwdOne
End Sub

Async Sub InitWeb()
    Await WebAccount.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
    WebAccount.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Site)
End Sub
```

Someone have any idea ?

Comment: `InitWeb()` is not awaited. Move the code in that method to the `Loaded` / `Load` event handler, make the handler `async` and await there `WebAccount.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`. Subscribe to `BasicAuthenticationRequested` after -- Event handlers can be `async void` (`async sub`), other methods, not so much

Comment: Thanks a lot . I no longer have the error. But I don't have the request for the credentials.

Comment: Did you add the `BasicAuthenticationRequested` handler after `Await WebAccount.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` and before `.Navigate()`?

Comment: Yes I added like that

Comment: Well, I cannot test your connection or EndPoint, I don't know whether the Service you're connecting to uses basic auth, NTLM challenge or you're trying to authenticate to a Proxy in between. You'll have to investigate that further

Comment: The connection use htaccess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425 and [Basic authentication for WebView2 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/basic-authentication?tabs=csharp)

Comment: @KenWhite, Yes I have my answer. And I fount why I didn't have the authentification request. I was in debug mode. In mode release, I have the request. But I don't know why .

Comment: Most likely due to improper CoreWebView2 initialization. Delete the `UserDataFolder ` prior to execution to verify.