# WebView2 fails to render local html page

Tags: c#, webview2

I've written an application that utilizes WebView2 in a Winform.  It displays a local HTML file on a form.  The debug version runs fine from within Visual Studio 2022.  The Release version runs correctly when executed from File Explorer.

I created an installer to load the application on a separate machine.  In testing the installation process, I found that the HTML page is not rendered in the installed version.

The HTML page source is downloaded to my machine from a web page.  I know this is happening because I can see it in File Explorer.  However, the WebView2 control on the form never renders the HTML source.

The WebView2 runtime is installed at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\109.0.1518.78

The code I use for rendering is:

```
string path = Path.Combine(_tempFolder, servicehtml);

try
{
  webView.CreationProperties = new 
  Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties();
  webView.CreationProperties.BrowserExecutableFolder = 
   Properties.Resources.webview2_runtime_folder;

  webView.Source = new Uri(path);
}
catch (Exception excp)
{
  MessageBox.Show(excp.Message);

  WriteLog(LogType.Info, Properties.Resources.ERR_WEBVIEW2_FAILURE, new object[] 
     {excp.Message });
}
```

I set the BrowserExecutableFolder according to the discussion in [Details about the Fixed Version runtime distribution mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#details-about-the-fixed-version-runtime-distribution-mode)

What am I missing that prevents the HTML from rendering correctly?

**UPDATE**:

I changed the above code to:

```
webView.CreationProperties = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties();
webView.CreationProperties.BrowserExecutableFolder = 
  Properties.Resources.webview2_runtime_folder;
webView.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = _tempFolder;    //<=====

webView.Source = new Uri(path);
```

Adding the UserDataFolder allowed me to change where my HTML file was located.

**Note**: The WebView2 runtime will create an "*EBWebView*" subfolder at the *UserDataFolder* path.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425 . It' VB.NET, but should be easy to convert - most notably you need to specify the `UserDataFolder` otherwise it will attempt be created in the same location as the executable which may fail (`%ProgramFiles%` requires administrator privileges).  You also need to review the [WebView2 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp) to ensure that your  MS Edge version meets the requirements for the WebView2 version you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was able to use the info you provided to work through a solution.  I've updated my post.