# Need to get distance between two Google map locations

Tags: vb.net, google-maps-api-2, webview2

I have a VB.NET WinForms application. I am using a webview2 control as a web browser. Actually I don't need to make general browsing, rather I just need to open Google maps, then enter two locations, and then get the Google map distance between both locations that I entered. But although my webview2 control shows the complete Google map and the user can get the path between any two locations as shown in the picture:

[image: A sample from Google maps]

But there is a problem: I need to fetch three values out from the webview2 control and show them in three separate text boxes, i.e.

Location1: (In string format)
Location2: (In string format)
Distance: 7.2km (In numeric format)

I need these three values to show them in separate text boxes and then further I need to save these three values in a database.

I developed this application for a transportation company and the three values explained above will make a complete transportation route.

Do I need to use any other control instead of webview2 to fulfill my need?

I think I have cleared what I need in fact.

If anyone can help in this regard, I will be very very grateful.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Private Sub txtSearc_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSearch.KeyDown
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
      Try
         Dim queryaddress As New System.Text.StringBuilder
         queryaddress.Append("https://www.google.com/maps?q=")
         If txtSearch.Text <> "" Then
            queryaddress.Append(txtSearch.Text + "," & "+")
         End If
         MyWebView_.CoreWebView2.Navigate(txtSearch.Text)

      Catch ex As Exception
         Exit Sub
      End Try
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do any of the answers in [How do I capture text from a HTML element given its id="" from a WebView2 in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840363/how-do-i-capture-text-from-a-html-element-given-its-id-from-a-webview2-in-vb) help?

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect case where you should use an API rather than doing web-scraping (as you do right now). Google Maps can change its UI at any time, which would break your web-scraping approach. Also, the UI is made to be human-readable rather than being machine-readable (which makes it difficult to parse for machines).

Instead, you should use the [Google Maps Routes API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/overview). Your application can talk to Google Maps directly, and Google will tell you all the info you need in a machine-readable form. The downside of course is that you need to pay Google per API-request, but since you seem to create a commercial product, you could forward that cost to your customer.

*(Note: I am not affiliated with Google in any way.)*