# how to Print directly html to a specified printer with webview2 in VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, webview2

I'm trying to Print directly html to a specified printer with webview2 in VB.NET.

As per the link below although in the link below using the C# program language:

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print?tabs=dotnetcsharp)

but I have an error in the code below :

`printSettings = WebViewEnvironment.CreatePrintSettings()` >> `WebViewEnvironment is not declared`

Please Guide Me.

Thanks

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Public Class Form1
    Private Function ToHtml2() As String
        Dim html =
          <html>
              <head>
                  <title>Basic Web Page</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                Hello World!
            </body>
          </html>
        Return html.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click
        Await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
        MyWebView.NavigateToString(ToHtml2())
    End Sub
    Async Sub PrintToPrinter()
        Dim printerName As String = GetPrinterName("ImagePrinter Pro")
        Dim printSettings As CoreWebView2PrintSettings = GetSelectedPrinterPrintSettings(printerName)
        Dim title As String = MyWebView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle
        Try
            Dim printStatus As CoreWebView2PrintStatus = Await MyWebView.CoreWebView2.PrintAsync(printSettings)

            If printStatus = CoreWebView2PrintStatus.Succeeded Then
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Printing " & title & " document to printer succeeded", "Print to printer")
            ElseIf printStatus = CoreWebView2PrintStatus.PrinterUnavailable Then
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Selected printer is not found, not available, offline or error state", "Print to printer")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(Me, "Printing " & title & " document to printer is failed", "Print")
            End If
        Catch e1 As ArgumentException
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid settings provided for the specified printer", "Print")
        Catch e2 As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Printing " & title & " document already in progress", "Print")
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Gets the printer name by displaying the list of installed printers to the user and
    ' returns the name of the user's selected printer.
    Private Function GetPrinterName() As String
        ' Use GetPrintQueues() of LocalPrintServer from System.Printing to get the list of locally installed printers.
        ' Display the list of printers to the user and get the desired printer to use.
        ' Return the name of the selected printer.
    End Function

    ' Gets the print settings for the selected printer.
    ' You can also get the capabilities from the native printer API, and display them 
    ' to the user to get the print settings for the current webpage and for the selected printer.
    Private Function GetSelectedPrinterPrintSettings(ByVal printerName As String) As CoreWebView2PrintSettings
        Dim printSettings As CoreWebView2PrintSettings = Nothing
        printSettings = WebViewEnvironment.CreatePrintSettings()
        printSettings.ShouldPrintBackgrounds = True
        printSettings.ShouldPrintHeaderAndFooter = True

        Return printSettings

        ' or
        ' Get PrintQueue for the selected printer and use GetPrintCapabilities() of PrintQueue from System.Printing
        ' to get the capabilities of the selected printer.
        ' Display the printer capabilities to the user along with the page settings.
        ' Return the user selected settings.
    End Function

End Class
```

update code from answer @user246821
`Await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`
I moved it from form_load to button event

```
Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click
        Await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
        MyWebView.NavigateToString(ToHtml2())
        Select Case (Await PrintToDefaultPrinter())
            Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.Succeeded
                Debug.WriteLine($"Printing successful: '{MyWebView.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle}'")
            Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.PrinterUnavailable
                Debug.WriteLine("The default printer is unavailable.")
            Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.OtherError
                Debug.WriteLine("Error while rinting to the default printer ")
        End Select
    End Sub
```

the result of the output is empty
[image: result output]

Comment: On that page, directly above the snippet that calls `WebViewEnvironment.CreatePrintSettings` is a link to the `CoreWebView2Environment.CreatePrintSettings`, so it seems fairly obvious that that is the method that is being called, so `WebViewEnvironment` refers to an instance of the `CoreWebView2Environment` class. How you get that instance, I'm not sure, but that's something to look into. Maybe the `WebView2` has an `Environment` property or the like.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `How you get that instance` I got from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print?tabs=dotnetcsharp)

Comment: OMG. You already provided that link. I can read what you wrote, even if you can't read what I wrote. Try again. I said that I don't know how you get an instance of the `CoreWebView2Environment` class but that's what you apparently need to do, so go make an effort to find out how.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Hopefully there is a solution to solve the problem.

Comment: `WebViewEnvironment` is just `[WebView2].CoreWebView2.Environment`. You should have `dim env = CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync("", nothing, nothing)` (just default values) before the WebView2 instance is created, and pass the `env` object to `[WebView2].EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)` -- The C# examples in that linked document are badly written (including `async void` methods, who know why)

Comment: @siwa86: Where are the two lines of code that are above those lines (in my post)? One should specify the location of the `UserDataFolder` to ensure that it's in a location that the uer has write access to. Also,  I don't believe that`NavigateToString` waits for the HTML to load before continuing execution so I'm not sure your approach will work correctly.

Comment: @user246821 , Thank you for your reply, `Where are the two lines of code that are above those lines (in my post)` I use your code 'Print to default printer' I also update the code in the post so print happens the second time, the first is blank and the second there is output . ` I don't believe thatNavigateToString waits for the HTML to load ` is there a workaround can wait for navigatetostring and then do a print in button event

Comment: _is there a workaround can wait for navigatetostring and then do a print in button event_: @siwa86: One has to understand how _WebView2_ works, and design ones application taking that into consideration.  It's unclear why you're so focused on putting all of the code in the button `Click` event handler. I recommend learning more about how _WebView2_ works, and then choosing from the available possibilities. One possibility, as I've shown in my post, is to ensure that there is a delay between loading (ie: navigating to) the HTML and clicking the button.

Comment: In the code I posted, the delay is implicit, because it's assumed that the user will wait for the HTML to appear, prior to clicking the button. One may also try subscribing to some of the events of _WebView2_ such as [WebView2.NavigationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55) and [CoreWebView2.DOMContentLoaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.domcontentloaded?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55)

Comment: @user246821 , 
Thank you for your advice and I use the webview2 control only to print

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to print from [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) in VB.NET.

The following assumes that one has created a *Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)* which has a form named *Form1*. In the designer, double-click the form (ex: Form1) to add the *Load* event handler.

**Add Reference** (System.Printing)

- In VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Select **Assemblies**
- Check **System.Printing**
- Click **OK**

**Add a button to the form** (name: btnPrint) and double-click the button to add the *Click* event handler

**Add/install NuGet package**: Microsoft.Web.WebView2

**Add a WebView2 control to the form** (name: WebView21)

If one explicitly initializes *CoreWebView2*, one can wait for initialization to complete by using the *Await* keyword.

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms
Imports System.Printing

Public Class Form1
    Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'set UserDataFolder
        Dim userDataFolder As String = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
        WebView21.CreationProperties = New CoreWebView2CreationProperties() With {.UserDataFolder = userDataFolder}

        'explicitly initialize CoreWebView2
        Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()

        WebView21.NavigateToString(ToHtml2)
    End Sub


    Private Function ToHtml2() As String
        Dim html =
          <html>
              <head>
                  <title>Basic Web Page</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                Hello World!
            </body>
          </html>
        Return html.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

For additional information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425).

---

Next, let's look at the code for printing.

**Option 1** (print to default printer):

**Note**: The code below is adapted from [Printing from WebView2 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print?tabs=dotnetcsharp).

```
Private Async Function PrintToDefaultPrinter() As Task(Of CoreWebView2PrintStatus)
    'Prints the current webpage, using the default printer and page settings.
    'Passing null for PrintSettings causes the default print settings to be used.

    'print to default printer
    Dim printStatus As CoreWebView2PrintStatus = Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.PrintAsync(Nothing)

    Return printStatus
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click

    'print to printer
    'Dim printStatus As CoreWebView2PrintStatus = Await PrintToDefaultPrinter()

    Select Case (Await PrintToDefaultPrinter())
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.Succeeded
            Debug.WriteLine($"Printing successful: '{WebView21.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle}'")
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.PrinterUnavailable
            Debug.WriteLine("The default printer is unavailable.")
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.OtherError
            Debug.WriteLine("Error while rinting to the default printer ")
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

**Option 2** (print to specified printer)

**Note**: The code below is adapted from [Printing from WebView2 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print?tabs=dotnetcsharp) and [PrintServer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printserver?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)

```
Private Function GetPrinterNameDefault() As String
    Return System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue().Name
End Function

Private Function GetPrinterNames(uncPrintServerName As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim printerNames As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    'must be a print server that the user has full print access to
    'ex: \\printServer123
    Dim pServer As PrintServer = New PrintServer(uncPrintServerName)

    For Each pq As PrintQueue In pServer.GetPrintQueues()
        Debug.WriteLine($"Queue Name: '{pq.Name}' Description: '{pq.Description}'")

        'add
        printerNames.Add(pq.Name)
    Next

    Return printerNames
End Function

Private Async Function PrintToSpecifiedPrinter(name As String) As Task(Of CoreWebView2PrintStatus)

    Dim printSettings As CoreWebView2PrintSettings = WebView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreatePrintSettings()

    'ToDo: set desired property values
    printSettings.ShouldPrintBackgrounds = True
    printSettings.ShouldPrintHeaderAndFooter = False
    printSettings.PrinterName = name

    'print to specified printer
    Dim printStatus As CoreWebView2PrintStatus = Await WebView21.CoreWebView2.PrintAsync(printSettings)

    Return printStatus
End Function
```

**Usage**

```
Private Async Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint2.Click

    'get list of printer names
    'Dim printerNames As List(Of String) = GetPrinterNames($"\\{Environment.MachineName}")

    'get default printer name
    Dim printerName As String = GetPrinterNameDefault()
    Debug.WriteLine($"printerName: {printerName}")

    'print to specified printer
    Select Case (Await PrintToSpecifiedPrinter(printerName))
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.Succeeded
            Debug.WriteLine($"Printing successful: '{WebView21.CoreWebView2.DocumentTitle}'")
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.PrinterUnavailable
            Debug.WriteLine("The default printer is unavailable.")
        Case CoreWebView2PrintStatus.OtherError
            Debug.WriteLine("Error while rinting to the default printer ")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answers. for this line of code `Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async() WebView21.NavigateToString(ToHtml2)`  
Can I use it on the button event without the form load? and for this line of code `Return System.Printing.LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue().Name` I have an error `printing is not a member system` . Please Guide me

Comment: One only calls `Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` when initialization is necessary which is after one creates a new instance of _WebView2_.  Will a new instance of _WebView2_ be created each time the button is clicked? Refer to the [WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.ensurecorewebview2async?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55) for more information. Are you using _.NET_ or _.NET Framework_? Which version?

Comment: thank you for your response. `One only calls Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async() when initialization is necessary which is after one creates a new instance of WebView2. ` 
for this I have posted, so the output result is empty so how can I use it in the button event without in form_load. `Are you using .NET or .NET Framework? Which version?` I use `NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.2`

Comment: `System.Printing` for Assemblies I've done and no errors. Example print to specified printer . Mydefault print is "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" and I changed to another printer that is still on my local machine like this `Dim printerName As String = GetPrinterNameDefault("Microsoft Print to PDF")` but there is an error  `Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` Please Guide Me

Comment: @siwa86: I noticed that my post doesn't even have an upvote. Unfortunately, if what I've posted isn't helpful to you, then it seems likely that any other information I provide won't be helpful to you either.

Comment: Don't say that because your efforts helped me, your answer also helped me, only here I have an error printing to specified printer . `Dim printerName As String = GetPrinterNameDefault("\\server-pc\EPSON L350 Series")` `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` I tried printer sharing from the machine but still the error please guide me

Comment: In the post above, `GetPrinterNameDefault` doesn't accept any parameters.  Do you mean `PrintToSpecifiedPrinter`? Have you tried `GetPrinterNames("\\server-pc")`?

Comment: sorry I'm late to reply . `Do you mean PrintToSpecifiedPrinter?` yes, I mean `PrintToSpecifiedPrinter` . `Have you tried GetPrinterNames("\\server-pc")` I have tried this too . ` Dim printerName As String = GetPrinterNameDefault("\\server-pc")` and `Dim printerNames As List(Of String) = GetPrinterNames($"\\server-pc")` and `Dim printerNames As List(Of String) = GetPrinterNames($"\\server-pc\EPSON L350 Series")` I've tried this code and it still gives an error `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.` Please Guide Me