# Need better way to use HTML in a C# form when WebBrowser uses outdated IE11

Tags: c#, html, jscript

I am showing HTML in a windows form where I can edit and quickly see the results.  The following code works but if the "ShowString" has a reference to a site that does not allow IE11 then I get an error when the site is accessed.

```
public ShowPage(string ShowString)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" + ShowString + "</body></html>";
}
```

I tried several suggestions to fix WebBrowser but all they did was raise the IE to version 11 which does not help with sites rejecting 11.

I tried WebView2 but it has no DocumentText where I can pass in my html.  The only other suggestion was to look at CefSharp.  I was unable to get that package into my project and the example project I built did not look like it was useful.

I would like to avoid writing the HTML to a local file and shelling out a real browser. I looked at command line input to chrome but did not see a way to pipe in my HTML text.

The WebBrowser displays the HTML correctly, but if you click on a url some sites will reject the visit. [image: Image of error]
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Use WebView2 and the [NavigateToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.navigatetostring?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.2210.55).

Comment: As another commenter stated, use _WebView2.NavigateToString_. _WebView2_ uses MS Edge. See [Release Notes for the WebView2 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425) for how to properly initialize _WebView2_.

Comment: The issue is probably the User-Agent that is used in the connection.  Most systems default to the default browser User-Agent.  You need to change the HTTP  User-Agent Header in the client.  The server is rejecting the default user agent.  See : https://51degrees.com/blog/understanding-user-agent-string

Comment: Have you considered if they reject IE11 then they probably have a reason?

Comment: @Steve of course they have a reason.  The WebBrowser component brings up IE11 and that was what caused me to bring up the problem.  I was unaware of the ie11 till I got a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Using Liu's suggestion the following worked

```
        async void ShowStuff(string strIn)
        {
            await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
            webView.NavigateToString(strIn);
        }

        public ShowPage(string ShowString)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowStuff(ShowString);
        }
```

[edit] Unfortunately, WebView needs to be distributed with my app as it cannot run without it.