# Display HTML string in WebView2 control with VB.NET causes error

Tags: html, vb.net, webview2

I am trying to build an HTML string which I then want to display in my WebView2 control which is called WebView2_1.  The code is as follows:

```
Dim selectQuery As String = "SELECT name FROM chats;"
Using command As New SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, sqlite_conn)
    Using reader As SQLiteDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        ' Iterate through the records and display names in WebView2
        Dim namesHtml As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        namesHtml.AppendLine("<html lang=""en"">")
        namesHtml.AppendLine("<meta charset=""UTF-8"">")
        namesHtml.AppendLine("<ul>")
        While reader.Read()
            namesHtml.AppendLine($"<li>{reader("name")}</li>")
        End While
        namesHtml.AppendLine("</ul>")
        WebView2_1.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(namesHtml.ToString())
        'MsgBox(namesHtml.ToString())
    End Using
End Using
```

The error I am getting is on this line:

```
WebView2_1.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(namesHtml.ToString())
```

**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.CoreWebView2.**get** returned Nothing.

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Do I need to initialise the control in some way or have I made another mistake?

Thanks very much

Comment: _Do I need to initialise the control in some way or have I made another mistake?_: Yes to both.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425 and [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/).

Comment: Based on your profile, it seems unlikely that someone with your experience would make those mistakes with the HTML, did you use an AI to write this code?

Comment: Part AI, part existing knowledge, part guesswork.  I admit I was a bit lazy with the HTML string... need to add <body> and closing tags etc... but it looks sufficient to render... unless it is very fussy?  I have never worked with sqllite before and I last used vb.net about 8 years ago :)

Comment: I haven't tested the latest versions of [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/), but when I last used it, I found it to be rather particular. I recommend that you implement the information referenced in my post in regards to initialization.  As far as what you consider _good enough_ for the HTML probably isn't going to work with _WebView2_.  For the HTML follow the standards - use both open and close tags, and of course don't forget the _body_ tag.

Comment: Thank you very much - I have added this line to the Form1_Load event : WebView2_1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async().  I have also tidied up the HTML which was not up to scratch!  It is now working.