WebView2 Edge Runtime Crashing
I have a WinForms app in C# which uses the WebView2 control with Edge Runtime. Everything works well for the most part, except in a situation where a user clicks a control on a website displayed by Edge which should display a file/folder browse dialog box. If the location that Edge is trying to get to by default is not available (such as a network drive or a deleted folder, for example) it causes the whole application to crash. Its all wrapped in try { ... } catch { ... } but the exception still causes a crash - presumably because its coming from a source outside my application. Does anyone know if its possible to do one or more of these:

Trap these exceptions so the app doesn't crash
Force Edge to open these dialog boxes in known good locations
Clear the cache for Edge Runtime

Grateful for any advice - I can't be the only person that's come across this problem, but web searches haven't produced anything useful.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625883/webview2-vb-net-cant-get-webpage-to-load/70645764#70645764 (under Form1.vb look at WebsiteNavigate method).
